# Не могу запустиь приложение под пользователем из ком строки

Tags: linux, sudo, rpm

Мне очень надо запустить приложение(нужен именно mate-terminal) терминала под пользователем из командной строки, но я получаю ошибку:

```
[root@localhost 16:54 ~]$ sudo -u user -H mate-terminal

** (mate-terminal:3569): WARNING **: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
[root@localhost 08:31 ~]$
```

(Очень принципиально запускать именно таким образом)

Пожалуйста подскажите как это можно исправить?

ОС - Гослинукс(это как центос)

Причем я точно знаю что он так умеет, из трех устройств - одно запускает.

Comment: Так это ворнинг, а не фатальная ошибка. Или все-таки крашится? Что говорит `sudo service dbus.service status`

Comment: В идеале должно открывать еще одно окошко мэйт-терминала, но оно не открывается, больше собственно ничего и не происходит. По поводу `sudo service dbus.service status` пишет что всё активно всё зелёное(могу весь текст кинуть)

Comment: Вот тут есть похожая проблема и разные решения (причин может быть несколько). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421498/linux-gedit-i-always-get-gconf-error-failed-to-contact-configuration-server Попробуйте все по порядку. Там суть - либо не установлен dbus-x11, либо с правами проблема, либо другое.

Comment: что бы открылось окно у вас сессия должна быть под рутом. а вы по всей видимости под своим пользователем.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить что-нибудь другое таким же способом. У меня `sudo -u $USER -H xfce4-terminal` запустилось без проблем.